# Simulator under iOS 13.3 (Xcode 11.3.1) not functioning properly

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, xcode11

When using the simulator under Xcode 11.3.1 and iPhones simulating iOS 13.3, the simulation does not behave correctly.  It works correctly under simulator iOS 12.1.

I get no messages that I don't also get under the iOS 12.1 simulator launch.

The behavior should be when a user starts the app for the first time, he is redirected to the signin screen.  Instead it goes to the main screen (grayed out because there is no data). I can navigate manually to the signin screen and signin normally (device registers and appears on my online server) but the app should start downloading the database required to work.  It just sits there (no alertview that would normally launch the download).  If I relaunch the app, it again starts at the main screen, however at this point an alertview should appear that no database is present.  If I manually try to start the download (in a setup screen within the app), the progress bar that normally appears does not, just a label signifying what database is suppose to download.

All of this works properly on the iOS 12.1 simulator (Xcode 10.1) of the same type (iPhone 8 Plus).

Is this an Xcode 11.3.1 bug or iOS 13.3 problem.  I have customers using iOS 13.1 without any problems on actual devices. I am on a new iMac running Catalina, is it possible its a security setting to allow database download?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and I move back to Xcode 11.3. Guess it was not a stable update at all.

Comment: Hassan,  Are you still having the same problem with xcode 11.3.1?